# What does the condition means?

Tags: c++, pointers

I looked into a code like this. What does the condition means?

```
Node *root;

while(root){

}
```

Comment: A while loop should be explained in any tutorial. Please do some research before asking useless questions.

Answer (score 1):

This condition means the following
in C and C++

```
while(root != NULL){
//...
}
```

or in C++

```
while(root != nullptr){
//...
}
```

It is supposed that variable root is changed in the loop.

Otherwise you need some more condition within the loop to break it.

Answer (score 1):

It is used data structure LINKLIST where you want to go to last point or node of your data like this

```
while(root != NULL){
 ptr=ptr.next;
}
```

where is also a node pointer and it goes to forward to your data stored on different places

Answer (score 0):

That's means root is pointer, that is pointing to null or not pointing any node.

When we check or iterate it over linked list then we use directly while loop that is executed until condition not become false

```
While(true)

While(root)

While(root !=null)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Node *root;
>
> while(root){
>
> }
> ```

First and foremost, this exact piece of code is **undefined behaviour** because `root` is not initialised and has also no value set to it before the loop starts. But a pointer needs to have a valid value when it is to be used in a loop condition. Note that `nullptr` is a valid value.

If `root` was initialised (or set to a valid value afterwards), then the `while` would read as: *"Do the following stuff as long as `root` is not `nullptr`."* <sup>[*]</sup>

For readability reasons, it would be better to name this intention explicitly:

```
while (root != nullptr) {

}
```

---

<sup>[*]</sup> `nullptr` exists since C++11. In previous versions of C++, you would have used `0` or `NULL`.